# How to make 2 threads work alternatively in turn-wise

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads in my application (say threads T1 & T2). One thread has to generate data (for easiness lets say numbers 1-10) and another thread (T2) is responsible for displaying the data generated by T1. 
But it has to work in specific way like when T1 generates number 1, it has to delegate the handle to T2 (probably by going to wait state) for displaying the number. Once T2 displays the number then only T1 thread should start again for generating next number/data. Once it generates next number it has to goto wait and then T2 will display the newly generated value and once done it will go back to wait state and T1 will start again. Below is what I'm trying to achieve:
    T1 --> generates 1
    T2 --> displays 1
    T1 --> generates 2
    T2 --> displays 2
    .....and so on
Actually it is some metadata in my case and not number. But I specified number just for the ease in understanding my problem. I tried using both join & wait but if I use T1.join(), it makes my T1 thread to first complete the whole data generation part and then only T2 threads starts working which is not what I want.
[EDIT]
I agree that my above logic beats the purpose of threads. Actually I was asked this question in an interview. I tried explaining him using BlockingQueue for doing the same, but he seems not interested with my reply. So I thought of trying to achieve it without using BlockingQueue just for my learning experience.

Comment: Its just like a producer consumer program. You can use wait(), notify(), notifyAll() methods. You can follow [it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_procon.htm)

Comment: You are working at what is now an unnecessarily low level. Take a look at the java.util.concurrent classes. Maybe use a pair of BlockingQueue to link the threads together.

Comment: The idea of threads is to avoid waits and let things happen in parallel. What you are describing doesn't like like this at all. It sounds like a single threaded sequential piece of code. So my question is why would you want to try and do this in threads at all? it sounds like a lot of effort for no gain.

Comment: That seems like a bad dup. @JarrodRoberson

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I agree that my above logic beats the purpose of threads. Actually i was asked this question in an interview. I tried explaining him using BlockingQueue for doing the same, but he seems not interested with my reply. So I thought of trying to achieve it without using BlockingQueue just for my learning experience.

Comment: If you create a scenario where the producer only produces after the consumer consumes then there's little use in threading because you have two sequential threads. You should consider letting the producer produce as fast as possible to a limit. Let the consumer consume as much as possible. The consumer will wait for the producer if needed.

Comment: There doesn't need to be a blocking queue. You should think at a lower level and consider which i/o calls are blocking.

Comment: @drekka, It's homework.  I don't know where it comes from, but a lot of students have been asking variations on the same question these last few years.  Apparently some hack wrote a textbook about _how_ to use threads without having any clue as to what threads are _for_.

Comment: I wonder if the part of the homework is to question the design. It's certainly something I do if I see something that looks like  bad idea. Recently I was involved in an interview where the person applying was asked to solve a problem. Part of the problem was a deliberate design flaw. It was put there to see if the applicant would pick up on it and question it. In other words, would they think through the problem before trying to solve it. Told us a lot about the skills of the applicant.